# On special integer gaps.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Calling an integer square-in if it is not square-free or a square. If $A$ and $B$ are two consecutive odd square-in integers , $A\gt B$ , let $A$ and $B$ is not a multiple of $9$       . Can $2\lt A-B\lt 12$ ? Are any such counterexamples rare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the context of this. Just playing, do $153$ and $147$ count? Or do $148, 152$ get in the way by being non-square multiples of $4$?

Comment: 9 does not divide 147. So I might have to revise the limit to A-B < 6

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Have you tried looking at the first few square-in integers?  At least as far as $117$ and $125$...

Comment: +1. Are there infinitely many such 'pairs'?

Comment: @ Robert Israel; I revised the question so B is not a multiple of 9. 9 divides 117.

Comment: 125 and 135, 147 and 153, 275 and 279, 325 and 333, ...

Comment: Or if you want neither divisible by 9, try 725 and 735, 825 and 833, 845 and 847.

Comment: And yes, there are infinitely many. Hint: what can you add to 845 and 847, say, to make the first still divisible by 13^2 and 5 but not 5^2 and the second still
divisible by 11^2 and 7 but not 7^2?

Answer (score 1):

The gap can be as small as 2: $$5\cdot7^2 - 3^5 = 2.$$

In fact there are infinitely many examples, with positive density, since you can choose any number $n$ congruent to 1323 mod 1800. It can't be a square mod 8, nor can $n+2$, but $n$ is divisible by 9 and $n+2$ by 25.

Edit: Since the problem has been changed, the new counterexample is 125 and 135. The first counterexample with gap exactly 2 is A = 477, B = 475.

Edit: You keep [changing the problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts). Yes, there are still solutions with A and B consecutive with the property in question, not divisible by 9, and with a gap strictly between 2 and 10.  The first example is 825 and 833.

Comment: 9 divides 3^5 ; I revised the question so 9 does not divide B.

Comment: Great counterexample. I'll revise the conditions again so 9 does not divide A or B.

Comment: I'll restate some conditions so ; 9 does not divide A or B and 2 < (A - B) < 10.

Comment: Great info. Charles; I keep changing the conditions because I am trying to 'narrow' down the 'behavior' of some types of integers. This is a collaborative effort after all, if I wanted to keep all my researches to myself I would miss useful observation from other people.